# Web Developer Portflolio Using Themes

Tags: copyright

I am a student just doing some freelance work over my summer break. I call myself a web "designer" as people in my country are more used to that term when they want a website created. I develop websites according to my client's needs using free GNU licensed themes. I let my clients know that I use free templates and do not charge very much. In my website, I want to show the work I have done in my portfolio (somewhat claiming that I designed the websites). However, I did not design any of the themes I use. Is this illegal? Will it still be illegal if I state that I did not design any of those websites myself but I'm merely a developer using themes? Thanks!

Comment: You have answered your question: if you use GNU GPL licensed themes, you can do whatever you want with them and with the code, even sell them. Additionally, any theme or plugin for WordPress can be considered a derivative work of WordPress and so should be licensed under the same GNU GPL license. Read general information about WordPress license [here](https://wordpress.org/about/license/) and the full text of latest GNU GPL license [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html).

Comment: So this means I'm allowed to claim that I designed the templates myself if I've modified it? Are there copyright implications?

Comment: Adding a tag to specify which country you are in, or under which set of laws you want the question answered would be helpful.

Comment: A location is especially important for copyright, as fair use/fair comment/fair dealing rules vary greatly from place to place.

Comment: I can't add a new tag but I stated in my question that I'm referring to the GNU license.

Comment: "So this means I'm allowed to claim that I designed the templates myself if I've modified it?" -- you still have to give credit where it is due, but I second @kaiser. This is off-topic here.